# Performance issue when changing <svg> <image> xlink:href attribute

Tags: html, image, svg, glassfish, browser-cache

I want to change this attribute based on input type range value and when image is changed I want to display some other svg elements on this image. I have following parts of working code:

```
<div><input type="range" id="panoramas-slider" min="0" max="0" oninput="changeMapPanorama(this.value)"></div>

//set max range based on number of images
$("#panoramas-slider").prop("max", currentPositionPanoramas.length - 1);

//after image in changed display some other svg elements of image
$("#svg-main-image").load(function () {
            $(".position-" + currentPosition + ":not(.view-type-dynamic)").show();
            $(".items-standard:not(.position-" + currentPosition + ")").hide();
            $(".position-" + currentPosition + '.view-type-dynamic[data-isShown="true"]').show();
            $(".position-" + currentPosition + '.view-type-dynamic[data-isShown="false"]').hide();
        });

//when input range is changed replace URL with new one and change xlink:href attribute to location of new image
function changeMapPanorama(value) {
    var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + currentPositionPanoramas[value];
    window.history.replaceState({path: newurl}, '', newurl);
    getCurrentPosition();
    $("#svg-main-image").attr("xlink:href", currentPositionPanoramas[value]);

};
```

Everything works fine at start (images are replaced very fast with no delays) but I've observed some problems when there are let's say about 50 images and when I move range cursor fast few times from min to max and opposite - I have noticed that call to server is made for each image on this range even I've cached all the images (I am using glassfish server so I wrote my own Filter). For example:

[image]

And because of these numerous server calls (about 200 each second) I got these server errors:

```
[2016-02-23T15:04:21.314+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=175 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1456236261314] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[default]: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)...
```

Web page page on client is also getting slower and slower and I can notice huge delays between image replacement.

My question is if this approach is correct or should I use some different approach? Summarizing I want to display quite large number of images with range cursor (I want to achieve effect of panorama rotation) + I want to display some other elements based on currently displayed image. How can I reduce server calls so browser won't call server for each image if images are properly cached - I think this is the main problem why my web app is not working as it should.

Thank you.

Comment: Load 'em all and use the display or visibility CSS properties to show the one you want.

Comment: I have tried that too (I change it with attribute visibility to hidden or visible) but this also make server call each time to get image...

Comment: I'm not sure I believe you about changing CSS visibility resulting in a server call. In the unlikely event that's true for you, change the opacity to something really tiny but non-zero then. Although if the client is a mobile it may simply not have enough memory to keep all the images in its cache all the time.

Comment: Ok, I'll try changing opacity... I tested changing visibility in Chrome Developer Tools and each time I changed visibility server call was made (returning status 304 - not modified)...

Comment: Doing it in Developer Tools will get you bad information as they recreate the whole object when they edit attributes.

Comment: You are correct, servers call were not made at all, this was just shown in Developer Tools... I changed some code on front end and now everything works smooth but problem with java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host is not solved yet. I'm now trying to find out what is the cause of this exception...